# Почему скрипт начинает корректно работать только со второго клика?

Tags: javascript, jquery

К тому же, если убрать animate scrollTop, то приходится делать еще и третий клик

```js
function f() {

$('.unit').click(function(){
if ($(this).css('max-height')=='50px') {
        $(this).css('max-height','10000px');

     $(this).css('transition','max-height 1.0s ease-in-out');
  $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 150 }, 1000);
} else {
     $(this).css('max-height','50px');

     $(this).css('transition','max-height 0.2s ease-in-out');
     $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 150 }, 100);

}
});
}
```

```css
.unit {
overflow: hidden;
max-height: 50px;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="unit"  onclick="f();">
<h2>title 1</h2>
<p>параграф</p>
<p>параграф</p>
<p>параграф</p>
</div>

<div class="unit"  onclick="f();">
<h2>title 2</h2>
<p>параграф</p>
<p>параграф</p>
<p>параграф</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Потому что основной обработчик ставится внутри другого обработчика клика (который в атрибуте задан). То есть сначала по клику назначается обработчик клика, который показывает/скрывает текст, а при последующих кликах он уже выполняется

Comment: Я слабоват, суть понял, а дальше безисходность

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы стандартным методом `javascript` прикрепили обработчик `f()` события `click` на элементы, потом в нем еще раз прикрепляете обработчик того же события `click` методами `jquery`.

Вот правильный вариант прикрепления обработчика события с помощью `jquery`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.unit').click(function(){
 if ($(this).css('max-height')=='50px') {
  $(this).css('max-height','10000px');

   $(this).css('transition','max-height 1.0s ease-in-out');
   $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 150 }, 1000);
  } else {
   $(this).css('max-height','50px');

   $(this).css('transition','max-height 0.2s ease-in-out');
   $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 150 }, 100);

  }
 });
});
```

```css
.unit {
overflow: hidden;
max-height: 50px;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="unit">
<h2>title 1</h2>
<p>параграф</p>
<p>параграф</p>
<p>параграф</p>
</div>

<div class="unit">
<h2>title 2</h2>
<p>параграф</p>
<p>параграф</p>
<p>параграф</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
function f() {
    if ($(this).css('max-height')=='50px') {
        $(this).css('max-height','10000px');
        $(this).css('transition','max-height 1.0s ease-in-out');
        $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 150 }, 1000);
    } else {
        $(this).css('max-height','50px');
        $(this).css('transition','max-height 0.2s ease-in-out');
        $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - 150 }, 100);
    };
}
```

Ошибка была в том, что при вы прикрутили обработчик onclick 2 раза.

Также в плане анимации настоятельно рекомендую переходить на добавление/удаление классов на чистом JS, а не использовать задание свойств вручную в коде. Намного повысится плавность анимации и будет меньше кода.

Comment: Дмитрий, спасибо, но не помогло. Консоль выдает: TypeError: a is not an Object. (evaluating 'b in a'). А для плавности анимации использовал плагин http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/ , но здесь методом тыка не удалось на animate его наложить. Если кто пользуется и подскажет как, будет радостным событием

Comment: @Vadim здесь проблема где-то в другом участке кода "a is not an Object" судя по тексту ошибки речь идет о переменной a, которую вы пытаетесь использовать как объект (которым она не является). смотрите в коде эту переменную.

Comment: @Vadim по поводу плавности анимации здесь все просто. используйте добавление и удаление классов со свойствами анимации для получения нужного результата. скорость и кривые анимации можно задать через свойство transition. плагины jquery в принципе используют то же самое, только оборачивают это в несколько слоев, которые повышают нагрузку на вычисления и уменьшают плавность анимации.